# Conditional statement assistance and refactoring Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, conditional-statements, ruby-on-rails-5

I am working on an app that has a bitcoin API integrated,I am struggling with a conditional statement, and I think it's due to my lack of understanding of ActiveRecord or SQL methods.

This is the desired behaviour:

1. The API is called and generates and saves a Bitcoin address.
2. That same Bitcoin address needs to be displayed to the user until a payment is made to it.
3. Once a payment has been made and the user wants to make another payment the API needs to be called again to generate a new Bitcoin Address.

I have found the find_or_create method, but I am not sure how to use it in my implementation or which method to use to say "If it does not exist - do this"

The code I have thus far works if there is already an existing `Payment`, but if there is no existing `Payment` I get invalid or unknown method/variable errors.

> If a Payment exists, and the last Payment's amount is 0.0 or nil, just show the last Payment's existing Bitcoin address.

```
if Payment.exists?
 Payment.last.amount.to_f == 0.0 && Payment.last.amount == nil
 @last_address = Payment.last.btc
 @last_address
```

> Then else if the Payment is greater than 0.0 generate and save a new Bitcoin address.

```
elsif Payment.present?
 Payment.last.amount.to_f > 0.0
 @new_address = BlockIo.get_new_address
 Payment.create( btc: @new_address['data']['address'] )
  respond_to do |format|
   format.html { redirect_to '/save_btc'}
  end
```

> Else Just generate and save a new Bitcoin address.

```
else
@new_address = BlockIo.get_new_address
Payment.create( btc: @new_address['data']['address'] )
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to '/save_btc'}
 end
end
```

How can I refactor this code, and also how can I use find_or_create or if a record does not exist create a new record by calling the API?

The user is not required to do anything in the view, as once they click on Pay, the page that runs the above method is called. This is the route that I have and it works very well:

```
match '/save_btc' => 'payments#create', via: [:get, :post]
```

Any assistance or comments will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Edit: When there is no existing Payment I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `amount' for nil:NilClass:
```

Which shows to be related to the elsif line: `Payment.last.amount.to_f > 0.0`

`NoMethodError - undefined method`amount' for nil:NilClass:
  app/controllers/payments_controller.rb:17:in `create'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in`send_action'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:188:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in`process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in`call'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `call'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in`block (2 levels) in compile'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `call'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in`call'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in`_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in`process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:20:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in`block in process_action'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'`

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of the error you are getting in your question?

Comment: @CdotStrifeVII I have added additional information on the error in the question, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get the code to work when no Payments exists, in the if block I did:

```
if Payment.exists? && Payment.last.amount.to_f == 0.0 || Payment.exists? && Payment.last.amount == nil
```

And the elsif block I just had to change `Payment.present?` to `Payment.exists?`

This solution still feels very hacky to me, please comment if there is a better way.